# 'Lock request time out period exceeded' in Azure Data Factory when connecting with Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, timeout, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We use Azure Data Factory to copy data from source systems to our Azure SQL Data Warehouse. We have not had any troubles with this process until last week. Since last week we have been getting many 'lock request time out period exceeded' errors in ADF in pipelines and data flows that connect to the SQL database:

> Operation on target Copy_bseg_from_blob_master_to_dwh_sql failed: ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Lock request time out period exceeded.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=1222,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=112,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=1222,State=112,Message=Lock request time out period exceeded.,},],'

When have not made any changes to the SQL server/database itself, or to our Data Factories that could cause a sudden rise in these types of errors. Also, the errors seem to be happening at random and are not tied to any specific pipelines or data flows.

We have tried rescaling the SQL database to simulate a restart (since Azure SQL Databases can't be restarted..) but that has not helped. Also, we changed the new maintenance windows of the database to only on weekend days but the errors are still happening during week days.

Does anyone know what could be causing this sudden problem? Has Microsoft changed anything to databases and/or data factories that we are not aware of? What could we do to try and prevent these errors? We are kind of at a loss here.

Comment: Have you executed sp_who or sp_who2 to look for connections/spids blocked due to open transactions?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes I have, there are no SPIDS blocked by any transaction. Although I reckon you should check this right at the moment such an error occurs?

Comment: Yes, you really need to catch it in the act. A shame it's not on-prem, you could have configured an Agent Alert for error 1222 to email you whenever it happens.

Comment: Is the error definitely on the sink side, and not in selecting from your sources?

Comment: @JasonWelch well the error we are getting is a SqlClient error. Since the sink is our SQL database and the source is usually a file in a blob container. So I assume the error is happening on the sink side

Comment: @MatthijsvanKesteren thanks - you hadn't mentioned that the source was blob

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue in the last three or four weeks with our Azure SQL databases.  I have started to attempt to log the open transactions when this exception occurs, but so far, nothing has been reported.  I have spent several hours pouring through application code, but have not found anything.  I'm beginning to think this is not a coincidence:

select @@version

results in

"Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Feb 20 2021 17:51:58   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation"

I'm thinking Microsoft recently updated the SQL Server version for 2014 within Azure, as I think the timing was very soon after Feb 20 2021.

I'm going to submit a support ticket in the Azure Portal FWIW.